# Linked List for loop printing garbage c++

Tags: c++, printing, linked-list

I am using linked lists to simulate a computer lab, and I am trying to print the linked lists. There's an issue with printing using cout, it produces garbage until the terminal just gives up and sends a segmentation fault 11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct lab {
    string current_ID;
    int station_number;
    lab *link;
};

typedef lab* lab_ptr;


void print_status(lab_ptr& head1, lab_ptr& head2, lab_ptr& head3, lab_ptr& head4);

int main()
{
    lab_ptr head_lab_1;
    head_lab_1 = new lab;

    lab_ptr head_lab_2;
    head_lab_2 = new lab;

    lab_ptr head_lab_3;
    head_lab_3 = new lab;

    lab_ptr head_lab_4;
    head_lab_4 = new lab;

    set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations(head_lab_1, 5);
    set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations(head_lab_2, 6);
    set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations(head_lab_3, 4);
    set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations(head_lab_4, 3);


    return 0;
}



void set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations(lab_ptr& head, int n)
{
    lab_ptr curr;
    curr = new lab;

    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        lab_ptr temp = new lab;
        temp->link = NULL;
        temp->station_number = n+1;
        temp->current_ID = 'empty';

        cout << temp->station_number << " " << temp->current_ID << endl;

        if(head != NULL)
        {
            curr = head;
            while(curr->link != NULL)
            {
                curr = curr->link;
            }
            curr->link = temp;
        } else
        {
            head = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

This is literally my first time using linked lists, so the error can be something incredibly obvious that i just missed. Sorry for advanced if it's a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For the string member current_ID you need to pass the value using double quotes:

```
temp->current_ID = 'empty';
```

becomes

```
temp->current_ID = "empty";
```

Also you need to move the function void set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations(lab_ptr& head, int n) before the main()

Comment: I am also trying to print the whole thing with a function like this but it still gives garbage      
     lab_ptr iterator;
 cout << "\nLab_1" << endl;
 for(iterator = head1; iterator != NULL; iterator = iterator->link)
 {
  cout << iterator->station_number << " " << iterator->current_ID << endl;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You are making extra allocations, other place the list is not properly initialized. Initialize `head_lab_1` to `nullptr` (or just `NULL`)

In the function `set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations` remove `curr = new lab`

```
void set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations(lab_ptr& head, int n)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        lab_ptr temp = new lab;
        temp->link = NULL;
        temp->station_number = n + 1;
        temp->current_ID = "empty";
        cout << temp->station_number << " " << temp->current_ID << endl;

        if(head != NULL)
        {
            lab_ptr curr = head;
            while(curr->link != NULL)
            {
                curr = curr->link;
            }
            curr->link = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            head = temp;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    lab_ptr head_lab_1 = nullptr;
    lab_ptr head_lab_2 = nullptr;
    lab_ptr head_lab_3 = nullptr;
    lab_ptr head_lab_4 = nullptr;

    set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations(head_lab_1, 5);
    set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations(head_lab_2, 6);
    set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations(head_lab_3, 4);
    set_up_linked_list_for_n_stations(head_lab_4, 3);

    return 0;
}
```